# How to parse Proto Buf Message in Spark Streaming received from Kafka Stream in Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

Hi I am working on a Spark Streaming project. In this project I to have Parse Data received from Kafka Stream (Proto Buf Message)

I don't have any idea about parsing Proto Buf Mesage in Kafka.

I am trying to understand below code to get started with parsing protobuf message.

def main(args : Array[String]) {

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.
  master("local")
  .appName("spark session example")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").
  option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").
  option("subscribe","student").load()

val ds2 = ds1.map(row=> row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")).map(Student.parseFrom(_))

val query = ds2.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

}

Can someone please provide me some example to how to parse proto buf message step by step ? 
I just need some reference material of how to consume it in spark streaming application.

Comment: In your example Student.parseFrom(_) does the parsing. There are no more steps - not sure what you are asking? Alternatively, you can create a Deserializer and pass it in kafka configs and then you will receive Student objects back instead of byte arrays. For reference material on protobuf look here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#reading-a-message

Answer (score 1):

I used Structured Streaming in that way:

```
import MessagesProto #Your proto.py file
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf


def message_proto(value):
    m = MessagesProto.message_x()
    m.ParseFromString(value)
    return({'x': y,
            'z': w
           })
schema_impressions = StructType() \
    .add("x", StringType()) \
    .add("z", TimestampType())

proto_udf = udf(message_proto, schema_impressions)

class StructuredStreaming():

    def structured_streming(self):       

        stream = self.spark.readStream \
          .format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", self.kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
          .option("subscribe", self.topic) \
          .option("startingOffsets", self.startingOffsets) \
          .option("max.poll.records", self.max_poll_records) \
          .option("auto.commit.interval.ms", self.auto_commit_interval_ms) \
          .option("session.timeout.ms", self.session_timeout_ms) \
          .option("key.deserializer", self.key_deserializer) \
          .option("value.deserializer", self.value_deserializer) \
          .load()

        self.query = stream \
        .select(col("value")) \
        .select(proto_udf("value").alias("value_udf")) \
        .select("value_udf.x", "valued_udf.y)
```

Comment: what is `message_x()` function in your py file?